# What is the strength of current in electrolytes?

Tags: electromagnetism, electronics, electrochemistry

if a battery is connected to an electrolytic cell, **what is the magnitude of the current in the electrolyte compared to the the magnitude of the current in the wire?** This doesn't make sense to me because there are cations flowing in one direction and anions flowing in the other in electrolytes, so is the current twice the magnitude of the current in the wire? does ohm's law still hold? Is current not uniform in the circuit? I hope somebody can help. Thanks!

Edit: The question has been answered on chemistry stack exchange.